# Plank dock in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, plank

Is it possible to use the Plank dock in Lubuntu?
Will it get in the way of the taskbar?

Comment: Did you try installing it and see what happens? ;-)

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Tried installing it. Works fine with plank dock. I solved the problem with the taskbar by setting it on the top.

Comment: Yes you can actually move either plank or the taskbar to solve this problem.